# If objects are passed by reference how do I handle them in functional programming

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, javascript-objects

I have been playing with some code over the last few days and I am trying to get more into functional programming but I am at a road block. I don't understand how to handle an object. Essentially I have an object that I want to add key value pairs to. I understand in function programming you don't reassign you just make a new object with the added key value pair. I was thinking about putting the object in some type of container like 'Box'

```
const Box = x =>
({
  map: f => Box(f(x)),
  fold: f => f(x),
})
```

And then using the 'Box' and adding all my key value pairs, something like

```
const formData = obj =>
  Box(obj)
  .map(s => s.key1 = document.getElementById("value1").value)
  .map(s => s.key2 = document.getElementById("value2").value)
  .fold(s => s)

var emptyObj = {};
const test = formData(emptyObj);
```

I noticed that 'emptyObj' will have both key value pairs but 'test' will not. I know that I am either completely missing it or just not understanding the process. I have been watching

https://egghead.io/courses/professor-frisby-introduces-composable-functional-javascript

and it is great along with the ebook but there must be something that I am missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To create a new object (`Object.prototype`), you could `s => {...s, key1: document.getElementById("value1").value}`. Don’t try to be *purely* functional in JavaScript, though – it’s not super productive. JavaScript types just aren’t meant for it.

Comment: A lens would make more sense in this scenario than your box IMO.

Comment: A little crazy naming. `map` and `fold` is already concepts done on lists so I had a hard time reading this.

Comment: @Sylwester `map` makes perfect sense on the identity functor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do something like this:

```
const formData = obj =>
  Box(obj)
   .map(s => ({ ...s, key: document.getElementById("value1").value }) )
   .map(s => ({ ...s, key2: document.getElementById("value2").value } )) 
   .fold(s => s)
```

Note that I would not have used `map` and `fold` rather monadic names `then` and `bind`.

Comment: Can you explain the `({ ...s, key: document.getElementById("value1").value })`? I dont understand why it is `...s,` vice `s.key`. Also what do you mean `then` and `bind`, do you mean to just replace the name of `map` with `then` and `fold` with `bind`?

Comment: WTH is a "monadic name"?

Comment: @JustinGagnon The parens is because the `{...}` is not a block but a returned object literal. `...s` inserts all the keys/values of s into the result and then `key: ...` adds that resulting in a copy of `s` with one extra key.  Yes `then` from a Box should encapsulate the result in a Box and `bind` should not.

Comment: @Bergi Usually `then` in JS is used with promises which are monads. `bind` also but they don't enforce the type or the return to be the same. In haskell `>>=` is a monadic name but really the name is not special.  You could do the same with any name, perhaps `map`?

Comment: @Sylwester It took me a minute of playing with the code but I finally understand that enough to be able to use it and modify it as needed. Basically it copies the object and then adds a new key/value, super simple. Thank you.1

Comment: @Sylwester In JS, the monadic *bind* function (`>>=` in Haskell) is called [`chain`](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#chain-method). But I don't see any monadic usage of the Box type in the code here.

Comment: @Bergi and it's called `then` in ES6 promises. Actually this is a functor but it basically composes the same way and that is why I identified it as monadic. It's in the same essence Crockford called ajax libraries monadic.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `map` callback functions return the string (the result of the assignment is the right hand side), not the object whose property they assigned to. You would need to write

```
Box(obj)
.map(s => (s.key1 = document.getElementById("value1").value, s))
.map(s => (s.key2 = document.getElementById("value2").value, s))
.fold(s => s)
```

to get `test === emptyObject` (and have both properties on it).

---

That said, I don't understand what this "Box" is good for. It would be much simpler if you had just written

```
const formData = () => ({
  key1: document.getElementById("value1").value,
  key2: document.getElementById("value2").value,
});
```

Comment: Here is part of my problem, I know that the code works, thank you for that, however I don't understand why. Let me see if I can explain it as best I can.

Comment: You mean the code with the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)?

Comment: Here is part of my problem, I know that the code works, thank you for that, however I don't understand why. Let me see if I can explain it as best I can.  The `s` is just a variable name and could be anything, in this case it is referring to the obj that was passed in `obj`.  Then we create a new key value pair by using `s.key1 = document.getElementById("value1").value`  All this makes sense to me. I don't understand the `,s` at the end and I don't really get what part is my callback and which part is the assignment. Sorry if I am asking a lot everything I know I taught myself.

Comment: Ah, the assignment is one operand of the comma. It's parsed as  `((s.key1 = …), s)`. Maybe it would be better to write it out as `s => { s.key1 = document.getElementById("value1").value; return s; }`

Comment: So by returning `s` I return the object and not the value that was generated by geting the `.value`. That makes sense. So what did you mean by the call back? Was it the whole get value part and return statement?

Comment: The "callback" is the function that you are passing to `map`

Answer (score 0):

> I understand in function programming you don't reassign you just make
>   a new object with the added key value pair.

Immutability isn't purely equivalent to functional programming, but I expect from this statement that your desired result (which you do not explicitly state in your post!) is for `emptyObj` to remain its original empty object, and for test to be a separate object with the `key1` and `key2` properties.

The problem is that you shouldn't be using objects for this. Not because they're in opposition to functional programming, but because objects aren't true dictionaries, and don't have easy tools for doing this sort of thing. You want to use a Map instead. Maps are designed to be dictionaries, and more importantly, are iterators, which allow some shorthand and reduced cognitive load.

```
const Box=(x)=>({
    map: (key,value)=>Box((new Map(x).set(key,value))),
    clear: (key,value)=>Box((copy=>(copy.delete(key),copy))(new Map(x))
    ),
    fold: f=>f(new Map(x)), // EDITED to prevent leaking the original map
})

const formData=obj=>(
    Box(obj)
    .map('key1',document.getElementById("value1").value)
    .map('key2',document.getElementById("value2").value)
    .fold(s=>s)
)
const clearData=obj=>(
    Box(obj)
    .clear('key1')
    .clear('key2')
    .fold(s=>s)
)

const emptyObj=new Map()
const test1=formData(emptyObj)
const test2=clearData(test1)

console.log(emptyObj) // empty
console.log(test1) // both keys
console.log(test2) // empty again
```

I added the ability to immutably `clear` data as well as `map` data, to show how easy it is. I used a weird construct in the `clear` method because `Map.prototype.delete` returns a success boolean and not the Map, so I used a comma operator. These evaluate left to right and returns the last value.

If you want to get into immutables without being strictly functional, then there are immutable class libraries available for Javascript that would provide immutable Maps, or it would be easy to subclass one.

EDIT

OP has mentioned the need to do this in objects for JSON intercommunication. One can use a helper function to convert the Map to JSON:

let map=new Map([['key1','value1'],['key2','value2']])

```
const mapToJson=map=>(
    '{'+
    [...map].map(([key,value])=>(
        '"'+key+'":'+(value===undefined ? 'null' : JSON.stringify(value)))
    ).join(',')+
    '}'
)

console.log(mapToJson(map)) // {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
```

I had to add a specific check for `undefined` because `JSON.stringify(undefined)=='undefined'`, but the JSON spec doesn't recognize `undefined` and uses `null` instead.

This assumes string keys, but maps can use anything as a key. You can add error checking, or just assume you're only passing a Map with string keys.

Comment: Ultimately I am making a form that I will be saving locally using JSON. I went with objects since that seemed like the easiest thing until I needed to grab some form elements that may or may not exist and add them to my eventual JSON object. I was thinking that if I could put the object to be saved in some type of container then I could pass it around and modify it as needed. Like I have said above, I am self taught on all of this and I realize that most of my code is probably clunky and not even close to the "right" or "correct" way of doing things.